# Combine multiple lists into a single list

Tags: python

For this problem, the list values are given.

```
heights = [184, 177, 190, 188, 159, 166]
weights = [84.5, 81.8, 86.1, 92.2, 69.6, 72.0]
names = ['John', 'Ryan', 'Bobby', 'Pete', 'Esther', 'Jane']
```

I am supposed to make a nested list called person_data using the heights, weights, and names lists provided above.
When I do, I get this:

```
person_data = [ [heights], [weights], [names]]
```

I am told that len(person_data) should be 6, and len(person_data[0]) should be 3, but that's not what I'm getting.

If I write out the entirety of the three lists in person_data (i.e.)

```
person_data = [ [184, 177, 190, 188, 159, 166],
[84.5, 81.8, 86.1, 92.2, 69.6, 72.0 ],
['John', 'Ryan', 'Bobby', 'Pete', 'Esther', 'Jane']]
```

then the len(person_data) is 3 and len(person_data[0]) is 6, which would be the reverse of what we are told is supposed to be correct.

What am I doing wrong, or did the lesson mix up the answers?

Comment: The question wanted you to make a single list with 6 tuples that represent a person, not a list of 3 nested lists.

Comment: `[heights]` is a list of one list. Its lenght is 1. `[184, 177, 190, 188, 159, 166]` is a list of six numbers. Its length is 6. Remove the square brackets around `height`. Also, there are no 2-dimensional lists in Python. There are lists of lists.

Comment: You are exchanging the two dimensions. You should create an outer list where each item is an inner list representing one person with height, weight and name.

Comment: You are supposed to build a list that looks like `[('John', 184, 84.5),
 ('Ryan', 177, 81.8), ...]`.

Comment: Something like this: `list(map(lambda x,y,z: [x,y,z], names, heights, weights))`?

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes, [you can](https://realpython.com/python-map-function/#processing-multiple-input-iterables-with-map)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were asked to zip the three lists:

```
people = list(zip(names, heights, weights))
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a list of 6 lists with 3 items each (height, weight and name):

```
person_data = [
    [184, 84.5, 'John'],
    [177, 81.8, 'Ryan'],
    ...
]
```

You can do that in several ways:

1. Manually create a new list, iterate through old lists and add new item for each:

```
person_data = []
for k in range(len(names)):
    person_data.append([heights[k], weights[k], names[k]])
```

2. Use a list comprehension to do the exact same thing (but with "nicer" syntax):

```
person_data = [ [heights[k], weights[k], names[k]] for k in range(len(names)) ]
```

3. Use built-in python functions (namely `zip`) that already does this (except that it will give you a list of tuples and not a list of lists):

```
>>> person_data = list(zip(heights, weights, names))
>>> print(person_data)
[(184, 84.5, 'John'), (177, 81.8, 'Ryan'), ...]
# Note that inner items are surrounded by paranthesis (tuple) instead of brackets (list)
```